# Assembly language MS-DOS Calling variable within structure

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, masm

MS-DOS coding problem:

```
SEGBIOS  SEGMENT AT BIOSSEG
ORG     0
DB      3 DUP(?)       
;Reserve room for jump to 
;init code
BIOSSTAT  DB      3 DUP (?)       
;Console input status check
BIOSIN    DB      3 DUP (?)       
;Get console character
BIOSOUT   DB      3 DUP (?)       
;Output console character
BIOSPRINT DB      3 DUP (?)       
;Output to printer
BIOSAUXIN DB      3 DUP (?)       
;Get byte from auxilliary
BIOSAUXOUT DB     3 DUP (?)       
;Output byte to auxilliary
BIOSREAD  DB      3 DUP (?)       
;Disk read
BIOSWRITE DB      3 DUP (?)       
;Disk write
BIOSDSKCHG DB     3 DUP (?)       
;Dsik-change status
BIOSSETDATE  DB   3 DUP (?)       
;Set date
BIOSSETTIME  DB   3 DUP (?)       
;Set time
BIOSGETTIME  DB   3 DUP (?)       
;Get time and date
BIOSFLUSH    DB   3 DUP (?)       
;Clear console input buffer
BIOSMAPDEV   DB   3 DUP (?)       
;Dynamic disk table mapper

SEGBIOS ENDS
------ some code here ----
AUXIN:
CALL FAR PTR BIOSAUXIN
RET
```

---

I am having difficulty that why and how we can CALL BIOSAUXIN variable, because we can not call a variable. Because as i know only function or method or procedure can be called

Comment: It’s not actually a variable. It’s the label for code to be filled in at runtime with a jump instruction to the true location of the function. It’s a way to do something like dynamic linking.

Comment: It means that if we change the name of the label from BIOSAUXIN to something else. Then the program will not work. Isn't.

Comment: In other words BIOSAUXIN is a predefined BIOS variable.

Comment: In MS-MSDOS 1.25 When IO.COM is loaded into memory at boot time there is a JMP table (a table of actual NEAR JMP instructions each 3 bytes long) placed into memory (usually at segment 0x60). This JMP table is used to reach the default MS-DOS IO functions.

Comment: @vijayst It's something called a *thunk* or *trampoline.*  You can jump to it.

Comment: @vijayst: no the name doesn't matter. It's the position in the segment that matters. So if you reorder it or add or remove something in the segment, it will not work. But the name can be whatever you want (of course it makes sense to keep the name because then everyone else will know what it is).

Answer (score 1):

Even though these look like variables, what they actually are, are places where a `JMP` will be stored. Hence the three bytes reserved for each (one for the `jmp` and two for the operand.) Each one takes you to some section of code that ends in a far return to take you back to the line after `CALL FAR PTR BIOSAUXIN` which in this case is `ret`. This is often called a "jump table" or "trampoline".

You may be wondering, "Why not just `CALL` the destination directly?" It's for compatibility purposes. There were many different versions of MS-DOS, running on different hardware with different requirements. And if you bought a new computer that had a revised version of MS-DOS, you wouldn't want all the software you paid for to stop working. Having a jump table solves this problem for the programmer and the end user, since it no longer matters if the addresses stored at those data blocks are different on your new computer than they were before. As long as the jump table's location in memory is the same on all computers and all versions of MS-DOS, you'll still end up doing the "correct" function by `CALL`ing the jump table offset rather than using a `JMP` to skip it.